# How to display images in Markdown on github generated from knitr without using external image hosting?

Tags: r, github, knitr, rstudio

I like uploading repositories to github that include multiple R Markdown and Markdown files.

Here is an [example of such a markdown file on github](https://github.com/jeromyanglim/gelman-bayesian-data-analysis/blob/master/exercise-2-11-1/exercise-2-11-1.md). And here's a screen grab.

---

[image]

---

The problem is that images do not display. You can click on the image, and you will go to where the file is stored.
The file referenced is:

```
 https://github.com/... /blob/.../myfigure.png
```

whereas I presume it needs to reference

```
 https://github.com/... /raw/.../myfigure.png
```

#### Things I considered:

**imgur:** I could use external image hosting (e.g., [see this example](https://raw.github.com/yihui/knitr/master/inst/examples/knitr-upload.Rmd)) by adding the following code:

`````
```{r setup}
opts_knit$set(upload.fun = imgur_upload) # upload all images to imgur.com
````
`````

However, for various reasons I don't want to do this (I have trouble uploading when behind a firewall; it's slow; it creates an unnecessary dependency)

**Rpubs:** There's also [RPubs](http://rpubs.com/) which is quite cool. However, at time of posting it seems more suited to single markdown documents rather than multiple R markdown documents. And it doesn't provide such a close link between source R Markdown and the Markdown document.

#### Question

- Is there a workflow for using R Markdown and knitr to produce Markdown files which when uploaded to github permit the Markdown file to display images stored in the github repository?

Comment: there's some option to embed images in html using some base64 encoding magic, I can't remember where I saw this though

Comment: @baptiste does this work for markdown? I had the impression that this only works for HTML but I haven't looked that closely.

Comment: Optionally you might run a regexp on each generated document which would change the `foo/blob/...` to `foo/raw/...` in the markdown files.

Comment: @JeromyAnglim it is y understanding that you can include raw html in markdown

Comment: I can base64 encode images in markdown if you want; just file an issue to me: https://github.com/yihui/knitr/issues Markdown is not different with HTML here; it is just a matter of `![](url)` or `<img src='url'>`

Comment: Thanks @Yihui . Here is the issue https://github.com/yihui/knitr/issues/298

Comment: @JeromyAnglim I have almost finished the work, but unfortunately I just realized github does not support base64 encoded images in their markdown... sigh. Just contacted them.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This used to be part of the minimal example, use

```
opts_knit$set(base.url='https://github.com/.../raw/.../')
```

See the changes [here](https://github.com/yihui/knitr/commit/a562a1792a07aa1eaaa159afd01c037ac86c585e) and [here](https://github.com/yihui/knitr/commit/e85848c6c2e3464fdc5d6c74154d19b049f32926).

Also see http://yihui.name/knitr/options.

**EDIT** [with update to restore base.url to former value

Regarding switching, you could define a function as

```
create_gitpath <- function(user, repo, branch = 'master'){
   paste0(paste('https://github.com', user, repo, 'raw', branch, sep = '/'),'/')
}

my_repo <- create_gitpath(user, repo)

knit.github <- function(..., git_url  ){
 old_url <- opts_knit$get('base.url')
 on.exit(opts_knit$set(base.url = old_url))
 opts_knit$set(base.url  = git_url)
 knit(..., envir = parent.frame())
}
```

Run with `knit` until you want to push to `github` then run `knit.github(..., git_url = my_repo)`

Comment: +1 thanks. I'm currently exploring how this would actually work in an elegant way particularly where you have multiple R markdown files in multiple folders. There's also the challenge of incorporating it into something like a makefile so that it is only added at the very end, just prior to pushing to github. Naturally if you add it before you've committed the image to github, then you can't see the image in your preliminary data analyses.

Comment: All you would have to do is run `knit` with `base.url = ''` until you wanted to push to github, then use the github url for the final run.

Comment: and then when you want to update the code, return it back to base.url='', and then when you update it change it back to the github base.url, and make sure that you type everything perfectly for every R Markdown file in every subfolder. I agree it's not that difficult, but I still think there is a small task in making it elegant and automated, especially when you have a repository with many R Markdown files. For example, I have one repo with 20+ separate R Markdown folders. But I guess I'm starting to drift into a slightly different question to what I originally asked.

Comment: Probably you need to set `base_url` to its previous value after call to `knit.github`?

Comment: This solution and the one below did not work for me. I still see "R Project Image" as a link, for example, but no image. https://github.com/RickPack/AnalyticsForward_2019/blob/master/README.Rmd

Comment: I solved the problem by capitalizing the PNG extension. Renaming the file on my hard drive did not solve the problem. Github still showed the capitalized extension from the first time I pushed out the files.

Answer (score 4):

What about the following code at the beginning of your markdown file?

````
``` {r setup,echo=FALSE,message=FALSE}
gitsubdir <- paste(tail(strsplit(getwd(),"/")[[1]],1),"/",sep="")
gitrep <- "https://github.com/mpiktas/myliuduomenis.lt"
gitbranch <- "master"
opts_knit$set(base.url=paste(gitrep,"raw",gitbranch,gitsubdir,sep="/"))
```
````

It is possible to tweak it so that `gitrep` and `gitbranch` will be reported by git. Here I assumed that I am one directory level below the main git repository directory. Again this might be tweaked to accommodate more complicated scenarios.

I've tested on github, here is the  [Rmd](https://github.com/mpiktas/myliuduomenis.lt/blob/master/2012-05-23-roziniai-akiniai/2012-05-23-roziniai-akiniai.Rmd) file and corresponding [md](https://github.com/mpiktas/myliuduomenis.lt/blob/master/2012-05-23-roziniai-akiniai/2012-05-23-roziniai-akiniai.md) file.

Comment: +1 thanks. I think something like that would be a good building block as part of some type of makefile and maybe a sed script to insert this command as needed.

Comment: And when it is not needed? I assume you want to look at the graphs *only* on github?